# How can I automatically assign extra params to my User with omniauth?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, authentication, omniauth

I have omniauth and devise successfully set-up for LinkedIn and Twitter.

When authenticating with LinkedIn, I am able to get the users name and email passed into the sign-up form automatically - but then it still gives an error and ask's the user to 'check the errors' which is bad UX given there technically are no errors.

How can I get them automatically assigned to the user during the create process, but only when they are present?  Here's the relevant code:

```
  class OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController


  def all
    user = User.from_omniauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"])
        if user.persisted?
        flash.notice = "Signed in!"
        sign_in_and_redirect user
        else
        session["devise.user_attributes"] = user.attributes
        flash.notice = "Please confirm your name and email"
        redirect_to sign_up_path
        end
  end
    alias_method :linkedin, :all
    alias_method :twitter, :all


end
```

From the User model:

```
  def self.from_omniauth(auth)
    where(auth.slice(:provider, :uid)).first_or_create do |user|
      user.provider = auth.provider
      user.uid = auth.uid
      user.name = auth.info.name
      user.email = auth.info.email
    end
  end
```